# CVA formula proof

Tags: cva, proof

I'm struggling to prove the CVA  formula in this [paper](http://www.r2-financial.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/RMFI-5-3_p252-272.pdf-Adobe-Acrobat-Standard.pdf).

Equation (3) is the result of computing the expectation of formula (1). Could you please show me how to prove that?

Comment: The link provided doesn't seem to work (at least from mobile safari) ?

Comment: Indeed the paper is not accessible. It may help if you can post here the paragraph that you puzzled.